# Change NSWindow background color with FadeIn Animation

Tags: macos, cocoa, animation, nswindow

I'm trying to build a Mac App (for the second time) and want to change the background color of my NSWindow with a fadein animation.

Right now, I've set the background image in this way:

```
    NSImage *windowBG = [NSImage imageNamed:@"greenBG.png"];
    [[self.window contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];
    [[self.window contentView] layer].contents = windowBG;
```

On a particular event, I want to change the "greenBG.png" to "yellowBG.png" with a fadein animation.

Doing this in iOS is simpler, but how can this be done in Cocoa?